# Selecting text of child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

I have following scenario like on the pictures below

1. I edited task with text 'task1'
2. Changed text to 'task2'
3. New text 'task2' appeared on the screen.

However I have problem to get edited text and store it in the variable.

How to select text(task2 in this case) from child div of div id="taskDiv" with jquery?

[image: task workflow]

**Code javascript:**

```
$(".list_of_items").on("click", "button.edit", function (){
        event.preventDefault();
        var myText = $(this).closest("div.text_holder").text();
        var textBox = "<div id='taskDiv'><form class='edit_input_box'><input type='text' value='" + myText + "' class='itembox'></form></div>";
        var deleteButton = "<button class='delete btn btn-danger btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button>";
        var editButton = "<button class='edit btn btn-success btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button>";
        var twoButtons = "<div class='btn-group'>" + deleteButton + editButton + "</div>";

        var textToSend = $(this).closest("div.text_holder").replaceWith(textBox); //replace with new word written 

        $("form.edit_input_box").on("submit", function(){
            var checkBox = "<label><input type='checkbox'></label>";
            //var noteId = $(this).closest("li").attr("id"); //take unique note id
            //sendUpdatedNoteToDb(noteId,textToSend);
            $(this).replaceWith("<div>" + $(".itembox").val() + twoButtons + "</div>");
        });
```

**Code html:**

```
<div class="form-inline">
                <h1>Learning jquery</h1>
                <form role="form" id="main_input_box_dub2az">
                    <label> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                        id="txtField_dub2az" name="Item" placeholder="Site note:"
                        aria-describedby="name-format" required> <input
                        type="submit" value="Add" id=btnAdd_dub2az
                        class="btn btn-primary add_button">
                    </label>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <ol class="list-group list_of_items" id="dub2az"></ol>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="container" class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code instead of this screenshot.

Comment: Also add javascript to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Screenshot is painful to read, make a pen or fiddle please

Comment: Try out `$('#taskDiv').find('div').text();`

Comment: added code as requested

Answer (score 0):

Try $('#taskDiv > div:nth-child(1)').text(); if you have many div's as children of #taskDiv